# Regular Expression to Recognize Even Number of Like-Characters in a Row

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to come up with a regular expression to recognize instances of 2, 4, 6, 8, (and so on) of a given character within a string.

I am using the vbscript regex engine.

In my particular case, I am looking to remove/replace instances of even numbers of consecutive single-quote characters within a string.

I can not seem to get my head around how to make it robust enough to find instances of any multiple of 2 without hardcoding it.

In non-regex coding, I would find instances of 2 or more consecutive single quotes, loop through each instance, and divide the count of single quotes by 2. If it divides evenly, then its a match, and if not, then it is not a match. I need help to translate that logic into a simpler regular expression.

Examples:

```
"it''s a lovely day"       --> should find one match group
"it's a lovely day"        --> no match
"it'''s a lovely day"      --> no match
"it''''''''s a lovely day" --> match
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The expression you're looking for is:

```regex
[^']('')+[^']
```

It searches for an even number of single quote characters (`('')`=two single quotes, `+`=occurring at least one time), between two characters which are not single quotes (`[^']` = character class consisting of any character, but not single quote).

Here's an online demo: http://regex101.com/r/wV6vE5/1